# Dbmail, why is variable "DIA" converting @body to null

Tags: sql, t-sql

Trigger for sending dbmail, there is one variable "DIA" that is converting the @body part of my dbmail to null when it is used, the trigger does generate the e-mail as designed as long as this variable is not used, and when it is used a e-mail is generated with nothing in the body

I have tried declaring the variable from inserted and as a select query based on the inserted part, same result. I get think that I am somehow converting the variable to null somewhere in my code but I don't see where that might be happening. Im including the full code because of this.  The problem occurs when I add @DIAstr or @DIAstr2 into the @body section of the dbmail

Apologies if I am missing something obvious, im not a DBA or in IT, I tend to get these projects since we don't have IT at my company and I do the best I can but im self taught and I know there are gaps in my understanding.

Quick clarification based on the last response, I realize that a null value in the string will cause the entire string to be null, I am pretty sure that is what is happening, I just don't understand why, as the value I have been passing through in test is not null.

[This is the result when I run the trigger as a select statement.  The statement returns three result sets, one for each declaration of the DIA (UDF_4) field, and one with the variable results as null.  Dose this make any sence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5ml1.jpg)

```
CREATE TRIGGER INCORRECT_PART_ENTRY_NOTIFICATION2
ON PART
AFTER INSERT
AS 

DECLARE @PART as VARCHAR(30) = (SELECT ID FROM Inserted)
DECLARE @DESCRIPTION as VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM Inserted)
DECLARE @COMMODITY as VARCHAR(30) = (SELECT COMMODITY_CODE FROM Inserted)
DECLARE @PRODUCT as VARCHAR(30) = (SELECT PRODUCT_CODE FROM Inserted)
DECLARE @THICKstr as VARCHAR(30) = (SELECT USER_1 FROM Inserted)
DECLARE @THICK as decimal(7,4) = (SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(USER_1) = 1   THEN CAST(USER_1 AS decimal(7,4)) ELSE null END FROM Inserted)
DECLARE @DIAstr as VARCHAR(30) = (SELECT USER_4 FROM Inserted)
DECLARE @DIAstr2 as VARCHAR(30) = (SELECT USER_4 FROM [dbo].[PART] WHERE ID = @PART)
DECLARE @DIA as decimal(7,4) = (SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(USER_4) = 1 THEN CAST(USER_4 AS decimal(7,4)) ELSE null END FROM Inserted)
DECLARE @THICK_CHECK as VARCHAR(30)
SET @THICK_CHECK = CASE WHEN @PRODUCT IN('STOCK HEADS','DOM "MISC"','EXP "MISC"','MISC WORK','SUPPLIES','TEST','UPDATE','TOOLING') THEN 'GOOD'
               WHEN @PART LIKE '%' + REPLACE(@THICKstr, '.', '') + '%' THEN 'GOOD' 
               ELSE 'NOT GOOD' END 

DECLARE @DIA_CHECK as VARCHAR(30)
SET @DIA_CHECK = CASE WHEN @PRODUCT IN('STOCK HEADS','RAW MATERIAL','STOCK BLANK','DOM "MISC"','EXP "MISC"','MISC WORK','SUPPLIES','TEST','UPDATE','TOOLING') THEN 'GOOD'
             WHEN @PART LIKE '%' + REPLACE(@DIAstr, '.', '') + '%' THEN 'GOOD' 
             ELSE 'NOT GOOD' END


DECLARE @CODE_CALC as VARCHAR(20)
SET @CODE_CALC = CASE WHEN @PRODUCT = 'SUPPLIES' THEN 'SUPPLIES'
                  WHEN @PRODUCT = 'TEST' THEN 'TEST'
                  WHEN @PRODUCT = 'TOOLING' THEN 'TOOLING'
                  WHEN @PRODUCT = 'MISC WORK' THEN 'MISC WORK'
                  WHEN @PRODUCT = 'DOM "MISC"' THEN 'DOM "MISC"'
                  WHEN @PRODUCT = 'PLATE' THEN 'PLATE'
                  WHEN @PRODUCT = 'STOCK HEADS' THEN 'STOCK HEADS'
                  WHEN @PRODUCT = 'STOCK BLANK' THEN 'STOCK BLANK'
                  WHEN @PRODUCT = 'RAW MATERIAL' THEN 'RAW MATERIAL'

                  WHEN @PRODUCT = 'UPDATE' THEN 'UPDATE'  
                  WHEN @PRODUCT IN('DOMESTIC','FINISHED GOODS','INTERCOMPANY') THEN 'UPDATE'                                    

                  WHEN SUBSTRING(@PART,1,1) = 'V' or SUBSTRING(@PART,1,1) = 'U' THEN 'B&R DOM'      

                  WHEN CAST(@DIA AS decimal(7,4)) < 30 AND CAST(@THICK AS decimal(7,4)) < .75 THEN 'DOM "A"'
                  WHEN CAST(@DIA AS decimal(7,4)) < 30 AND CAST(@THICK AS decimal(7,4)) BETWEEN .75 AND 1.25 THEN 'DOM "B"'
                  WHEN CAST(@DIA AS decimal(7,4)) < 30 AND CAST(@THICK AS decimal(7,4)) > 1.25 THEN 'DOM "C"'

                  WHEN CAST(@DIA AS decimal(7,4)) BETWEEN 30 AND 72 AND CAST(@THICK AS decimal(7,4)) < .75 THEN 'DOM "D"'
                  WHEN CAST(@DIA AS decimal(7,4)) BETWEEN 30 AND 72 AND CAST(@THICK AS decimal(7,4)) BETWEEN .75 AND 1.25 THEN 'DOM "E"'
                  WHEN CAST(@DIA AS decimal(7,4)) BETWEEN 30 AND 72 AND CAST(@THICK AS decimal(7,4)) > 1.25 THEN 'DOM "F"'

                  WHEN CAST(@DIA AS decimal(7,4)) BETWEEN 72.001 AND 120 AND CAST(@THICK AS decimal(7,4)) < .75 THEN 'DOM "G"'
                  WHEN CAST(@DIA AS decimal(7,4)) BETWEEN 72.001 AND 120 AND CAST(@THICK AS decimal(7,4)) BETWEEN .75 AND 1.25 THEN 'DOM "H"'
                  WHEN CAST(@DIA AS decimal(7,4)) BETWEEN 72.001 AND 120 AND CAST(@THICK AS decimal(7,4)) > 1.25 THEN 'DOM "I"'

                  WHEN CAST(@DIA AS decimal(7,4)) BETWEEN 120.001 AND 144 AND CAST(@THICK AS decimal(7,4)) < .75 THEN 'DOM "J"'
                  WHEN CAST(@DIA AS decimal(7,4)) BETWEEN 120.001 AND 144 AND CAST(@THICK AS decimal(7,4)) BETWEEN .75 AND 1.25 THEN 'DOM "K"'
                  WHEN CAST(@DIA AS decimal(7,4)) BETWEEN 120.001 AND 144 AND CAST(@THICK AS decimal(7,4)) > 1.25 THEN 'DOM "L"'

                  WHEN CAST(@DIA AS decimal(7,4)) > 144 AND CAST(@THICK AS decimal(7,4)) < .75 THEN 'DOM "M"'
                  WHEN CAST(@DIA AS decimal(7,4)) > 144 AND CAST(@THICK AS decimal(7,4)) BETWEEN .75 AND 1.25 THEN 'DOM "N"'
                  WHEN CAST(@DIA AS decimal(7,4)) > 144 AND CAST(@THICK AS decimal(7,4)) > 1.25 THEN 'DOM "O"'

                  ELSE 'UPDATE' END  

DECLARE @CODE_CHECK AS CHAR(1)
SET @CODE_CHECK = CASE WHEN @CODE_CALC = 'UPDATE' THEN 'N'
                   WHEN @PRODUCT = @CODE_CALC THEN 'Y' 
                   ELSE 'N' END

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SEND as Char(1)
SET @SEND = CASE WHEN @THICK_CHECK = 'NOT GOOD' THEN 'Y'
            WHEN @DIA_CHECK = 'NOT GOOD' THEN 'Y'
            WHEN @CODE_CHECK = 'N' THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N' END

DECLARE @MailSubject AS varchar(50)
Set @MailSubject = 'Incorrect Part Entry - '+@PART


DECLARE @MESSAGE as Varchar(max) 
SET @MESSAGE = (SELECT 'It appears that an error may have been made entering Part ID '+ @PART+'.' +
                        CHAR(10) +
                        'This e-mail was triggered either by descripencies in the calculated product code and the enntered product code, or a match between the values entered for thickness and DIA could not be made in the Part ID.' +
                        CHAR(10) +
                        @CODE_CALC + ' ' + @PRODUCT + ' ' + @THICKstr + ' ' + @DIAstr2) 

IF @SEND = 'Y'
BEGIN
      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @recipients = 'xxxxx@xxx', 
      @profile_name = 'xxxxxx',
      @subject = @MailSubject, 
      @body = @MESSAGE;
END

END
GO
```

Comment: `NULL + AnotherString` will be `NULL`. You can use `Coalesce( MightBeNull, '' )` to convert a null in a string column to an empty string (or other value, e.g. `Coalesce( PartNo, '(Missing PartNo)' )`).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I should have mentioned this in my post, Im still on SQL server 2008 so Coalesce is not an option.  But in addition to that, the value is not null, unless I am unknowingly converting it to a null somewhere in my code.

Comment: `Coalesce` may not be as old as dirt, but it was there when mud was invented. `IsNull` is a non-ANSI alternative. Try `DECLARE @DIAstr as VARCHAR(30) (SELECT Coalesce( USER_4, '(NULL)' ) FROM Inserted)` and similarly for `@DIAstr2` to see if that's where the problem starts, Standard trigger rant follows in the next comment ... .

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: lol, No equal signs to set either variable value.  I hate myself a little right now.  Thanks everyone, learned a few new things trying to figure it out so I guess I cant call it a complete failure.